# Macro doesn't show open mail

Tags: vba, outlook

Below is my macro to send an email but it does not open a new  email .

This macro is in the outlook rules.

Have you any ideas?

```
  Sub sendemail()

  Dim ns As NameSpace
 'Dim newMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Dim newMail As MailItem
Set newMail = Application.CreateItem()

With newMail
  .To = "aaa@bbb" <--adress to whitch I want to send an email
  .Subject = "test"
  .Display
 End With
Set newMail = Nothing

  End Sub
```

Comment: It is impossible that this is called in a rule. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472855/outlook-vba-cannot-sent-email-as-script-assigned-to-rule

Comment: You could delete this question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472855/outlook-vba-cannot-sent-email-as-script-assigned-to-rule to be sure the third one is not closed as a duplicate. If you are asked for or have more details just edit that third one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484303/outlook-vba-script-envoked-by-rule-doesnt-send-an-email

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add up the outlook reference:

[image]

There you go:

then:

```
Sub sendemail()

  Dim outlook As New outlook.Application
 Dim newMail As outlook.MailItem

    Set newMail = outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)


    With newMail
      .To = "email@address.com" ' <--adress to whitch I want to send an email
      .Subject = "test from Steph"
      .Display
      .Send
     End With
    Set newMail = Nothing
    outlook.Quit
    Set outlook = Nothing

  End Sub
```

Comment: I run successfully below macro   but when I try to run it as rule in Outlook it   did nothing                                                                                  Sub sendemail()
Dim newMail As outlook.MailItem
Set newMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With newMail
.To = "aaa@aaa.com"
.Subject = "test"
.Send
End With
Set newMail = Nothing

End Sub

Comment: i updated my answer. the problem may need to add the outlook reference. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Argument must be type **`MailItem`** or **`MeetingItem`** for the subroutine to be available in Outlook Rules Wizard.

Try this.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SendEmail(NewMail As Outlook.MailItem)

    Set NewMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With NewMail
        .To = "aaa@bbb"  '<--adress to whitch I want to send an email
        .Subject = "test"
        .Display
    End With

    Set NewMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Youre not specifying the item to create.  See here:

```
Private Sub SendEmail(ByVal workcenter As Integer, ByVal time As Date)
    Dim objApp As Object
    Dim objEmail As Object
    Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objEmail = CreateObject("Outlook.MailItem")
    With objEmail
        .To = "emailexampe@website.com"
        .Subject = "Multiple Shop Orders run for line " & workcenter & " at " & time
        .body = "TEST"
        .display
    End With
    Set objEmail = Nothing
    Set objApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Source: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?536558-RESOLVED-Outlook-late-binding

this version also uses late binding, so you dont need any additional references.